# Passing multiple parameters as one to a function

Tags: python, function, scipy

I have the following two functions

```
def single(x, param_a, param_b):
    return param_a + param_b*x

def multi(x, parameters):
    param_a_multi, param_b_multi = parameters[0], parameters[1]
    multi_result = 0
    for i in range(len(param_a_multi)):
        multi_result += single(x, param_a_multi[i], param_b_multi[i])
    return multi_result
```

I know that the original data is built using 2*5 parameters. My guesses are:

```
guesses_a = numpy.linspace(1,5,5)
guesses_b = [1]*5
```

I am trying to pass them in this form

```
guesses = [guesses_a, guesses_b]
```

to curve_fit (using made up data in this example):

```
from scipy import optimize
optimize.curve_fit(f = multi, xdata = numpy.linspace(0,1,100), ydata = numpy.linspace(0,1,100), p0 = guesses)
```

However, I get

```
TypeError: multi() takes 2 positional arguments but 11 were given
```

How do I pass `guesses` as 1 argument and not as 10?

Comment: Pass the parameters in a dictionary?

Comment: Does `single` always need to operate on pairs of values? Or is it enough for you that `multi` receives an arbitrary number of arguments? In the second case, consider using an asterisk (\*) to pack the arguments: `def function(*arg)`, where `arg` will be a tuple with all the positional arguments that you pass to the function when called.

Comment: `curve_fit` should explain exactly the arguments `multi` should expect, because that's what it will pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

From the `curve_fit` docs:

```
Parameters
f 
callable
    The model function, f(x, …). It must take the independent variable as the first argument 
    and the parameters to fit as separate remaining arguments.

p0 
array_like, optional
    Initial guess for the parameters (length N).....
```

Note it says `length N`.  I can double check the code, but if given 2d array, or list of arrays, it will flatten it.

```
In [16]: guesses_a = numpy.linspace(1,5,5)
    ...: guesses_b = [1]*5
    ...: guesses = [guesses_a, guesses_b]
    ...: 
In [17]: guesses
Out[17]: [array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]), [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
In [18]: np.array(guesses).ravel()
Out[18]: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

That's 10 parameters, plus `x` that makes the 11 in the error message.

Don't forget that `curve_fit` has to vary those `guesses` to make the fit.  Therefore your function has to accept the parameters as it generates them.

If you define

```
def multi(x, *parameters):
```

`parameters` will still be a flat array of 10 values; not two, or 2d array.

---

`curve_fit` does

```
   p0 = np.atleast_1d(p0)
    n = p0.size
```

and passes the task to:

```
res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
```

where that `p0` gets:

```
x0 = asarray(x0).flatten()
n = len(x0)
```